# css classes for html root element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i found this code via Google Developer Tools:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" class=" js canvas canvastext geolocation crosswindowmessaging websqldatabase no-indexeddb hashchange historymanagement draganddrop websockets rgba hsla multiplebgs backgroundsize borderimage borderradius boxshadow opacity cssanimations csscolumns cssgradients cssreflections csstransforms no-csstransforms3d csstransitions  video audio localstorage sessionstorage webworkers applicationcache svg smil svgclippaths no-opera no-mozilla webkit   fontface">
    </html>
```

and this code via html source code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"> </html>
```

obviously these classes get generated with Javascript.
But Why? Why so many css classes for html root element?

Comment: it's not my site. i'm just learning.. Yes.. that site uses modernizr..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

These get generated by [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/), as a means to identify what features are available to a user's browser.

Comment: i see.. but are these css classes used after they are generated??

Comment: that certainly can be by the sites css

Comment: That's up to you – if you want to use them do. Assumedly the original author wanted to use them.

Comment: they can be used by the css or detected by javascript to progressively enhance the site